# C++ Memory management for vector of Objects

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

I have a few questions/examples about how memory management works for Vectors.

```
    vector<int> vec1(10);
    vector<int> vec2(10);        
    vec1 = vec2;
```

In a case like this, vec1's old memory is unreachable now. Is it still a memory leak here or would vec2's old memory realize there nothing referencing it and get cleaned up?

In another example

```
struct foo
{
   vector<int> foo_vec(50);
   int* arr; 
}


void myFunction()
{
   vector<foo> vec(10);
   vec[0].arr = new int[50];
   vec.erase(vec.begin());
}
```

Since I used `erase()` on the first vector element which contained arr with the allocated memory, does `erase()` release that memory or do I need to release it manually prior to the erase? Also when `vec` goes out of scope, are all the `foo_vec` vectors in `vec` automatically cleaned up? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of

```
vector<int> vec1(10);
vector<int> vec2(10);        
vec1 = vec2;
```

the previous contents of vec1 are erased since `int` is just a POD. If the `vector` consisted of pointers to objects instead of ints and these were allocated with `new` you would have to delete what those pointers point to before you assign, otherwise you would end up with memory leaks which your second example shows:

```
vector<foo> vec(10);
vec[0].arr = new int[50];
vec.erase(vec.begin());    // this will *not* call delete on vec[0].arr
```

Normally what you do to make things simpler for yourself is to use smart pointers like unique pointers (or e.g. boost::shared_array/scoped_array). When the vector goes out of scope or you erase the vector the delete (or delete []) will be automatically called.

```
struct foo
{
   std::vector<int> foo_vec(50);
   std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr; 
}
...
vec[0].arr.reset(new int[50]);
vec[0].arr[12] = 42;
...
vec.erase(vec.begin());    // this will call delete[] on vec[0].arr
```

Comment: What if `vec1`and `vec2`consist of structs ? Will there be a memory leak then ?

Comment: it depends. when you put stuff in a vector you need to decide who owns the instances.

Answer (score 2):

> Does erase() release that memory or do I need to release it manually prior to the erase?

The rule: **Always use `delete` for each `new`.** `vector` ain't no magic - it doesn't know how you obtained that pointer, so it won't delete it, you need to do it.

> Also when vec goes out of scope, are all the foo_vec vectors in vec automatically cleaned up?

Yes, their destructor is called and they're deallocated. However, you will leak memory if the destructor doesn't `delete[] arr;`.

---

By the way, a piece of good advice: your code violates encapsulation. You should allocate (`new`) and free (`delete[]`) the memory pointed to by `foo::arr` in the destructor and the constructor (`foo::foo()` and `foo::~foo()`), respectively.

Finally, the obligatory question: why `foo::arr` isn't a `vector<int>` itself?

Comment: Oh these were just examples I made up to help me understand better, not actual code I'm writing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Of course it will be cleaned.
2. No, if `destructor` of `foo` doesn't do this (or if you don't do it manually before erase).